# jQuery.parseJSON not appending any values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Problem:** When I load the page, the get_user_list(); does not work. It is not appending any of the encoded JSON returned. The *jQuery.parseJSON*, *$.parseJSON* OR *jQuery.getJSON* does **not** work.

**My guess of what is happening:**
Perhaps I should try this online to see if it actually works. I am fairly sure that it is the parseJSON the one that is not working.

**What have I tried to fix my problem?**

1. I tried using $.getJSON but that did not work, as it gave me a 403
   error.
2. I tried downloaded the jQuery library and loaded it locally instead of grabbing it from Google's library
3. Using addslashes() when inserting data into the database.

This is the AJAX that I am using.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        get_user_list();
    });

function get_user_list() {
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        task:   "get_user_list"
    }, 
    function(data) {
        $('#responseText').val(data); //This ACTUALLY WORKS
        var people = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //Problem here
        for (var i in people) {
            var opt = "<option value='" + people[i].id + "'>" + people[i].first_name + "</option>";
            $('#subsriber').append(opt);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select id="subscriber">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Subscriber</option>
</select>
```

This is a piece of encoded JSON that would be returned as the "data":

```
[{"id":"1","first_name":"Mother","last_name":"Teresa"},{"id":"2","first_name":"Martin","last_name":"Lutherking"}]
```

If anyone can guide me into the right direction, that would be great. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are getting an already parsed data, so try

```
function get_user_list() {
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        task: "get_user_list"
    }, function (people) {
        $('#responseText').val(people); //This ACTUALLY WORKS

        $.each(people, function (idx, person) {
            var opt = "<option value='" + person.id + "'>" + person.first_name + "</option>";
            $('#subsriber').append(opt);
        })
    }, 'json').fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Both the old and your revised version of the code. I am not getting anything else other than [object Object],[object Object] now. Perhaps I did it wrong? Why is people being passed into the function?